# Navigate objects from a path provided as a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings

Recently I wrote a validator for some objects. To increase usability the validator gives the user hints on how to fix some of the found issues. Since the application is around something programmatic, and that many of the issues wouldn't make sense without identifying a path to an object; I decided to build a navigator.

At first I didn't have this so I just used `getattr` and defaulted to the very helpful `<Unknown>` value if that failed to get the value. This resulted in some useful; some less useful messages.

Upon completing the V1 of the below code I had the clever idea of allowing the validator to just fix the fixable issues. Since this is a flag, it allows the user to get a working version and then come back and clean it up once it works. However this quickly showed some errors in my initial design as I didn't plan for setting and deleting values.

---

I feel like given how catastrophically V1 failed V2 isn't going to be much better. Unlike with V1, with V2 I followed TDD, and so the code slowly built up over some time. This has caused a lot of the nuance to just disappear and I find `_parse` to be a bit of an eyesore.

I have added a full description on what this achieves in the code, however a short overview would be that it's similar to `eval()` just it's not evil.

- Attribute indexing similar to standard Python. `data.foo.bar.baz`.
- Escape special (all) characters using a slash \.
- Index items using brackets. `data["key1"]["key2"]`.
- Allow two literals strings or integers, `1` and `"key"`.

However it acts quite a bit differently as each level has `data` implicitly prepended - if it is not a literal.

- `[["key"]]` would be the same as `data[data["key"]]` in Python, and
- `[foo]` would be the same as `data[data.foo]` rather than `data["foo"]`.

I would like a review of any or all of my code. However changes that reduce version compatibility are generally unhelpful.

```py
import dataclasses
from typing import Any, Iterator, List, NoReturn, Optional, Union, cast


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Attr:
    _index: "Path"

    def get(self, root_obj: Any, obj: Any) -> Any:
        """Get attribute from object."""
        return getattr(obj, self._index.get(root_obj))

    def set(self, root_obj: Any, obj: Any, value: Any) -> Any:
        """Set object's attribute to value."""
        setattr(obj, self._index.get(root_obj), value)

    def delete(self, root_obj: Any, obj: Any) -> Any:
        """Delete object's attribute."""
        delattr(obj, self._index.get(root_obj))


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Item:
    _index: "Path"

    def get(self, root_obj: Any, obj: Any) -> Any:
        """Index object."""
        return obj[self._index.get(root_obj)]

    def set(self, root_obj: Any, obj: Any, value: Any) -> Any:
        """Set object's index to value."""
        obj[self._index.get(root_obj)] = value

    def delete(self, root_obj: Any, obj: Any) -> Any:
        """Delete object's index."""
        del obj[self._index.get(root_obj)]


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Literal:
    _index: Any

    def get(self, root_obj: Any, obj: Any) -> Any:
        """Get literal value."""
        return self._index

    def set(self, root_obj: Any, obj: Any, value: Any) -> NoReturn:
        """Unable to change a literal, the path is misconfigured."""
        raise TypeError("Can't set to a literal")

    def delete(self, root_obj: Any, obj: Any) -> NoReturn:
        """Unable to delete a literal, the path is misconfigured."""
        raise TypeError("Can't delete a literal")


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Path:
    _nodes: List[Union[Attr, Item, Literal]]

    @classmethod
    def from_str(cls, value: str) -> "Path":
        """
        Build a path from string form.

        Without any special characters this works the same way that
        `getattr` and friends works.

        >>> assert '1'.isnumeric()
        >>> assert getattr('1', 'isnumeric')()
        >>> assert Path.from_str('isnumeric').get('1')()

        You can get the same functionality as attrgetter with one
        argument by splitting by period.

        >>> import datetime
        >>> import operator
        >>> assert (
        ...     operator.attrgetter('date.today')(datetime)()
        ...     == Path.from_str('date.today').get(datetime)()
        ... )

        You can index an item using square brackets.
        Like we're used to in Python.

        >>> data = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
        >>> assert data[1] == 'bar'
        >>> assert Path.from_str('[1]').get(data) == 'bar'

        You can index a dictionary by indexing by a string literal.

        >>> data = {'foo': 'bar'}
        >>> assert data['foo'] == 'bar'
        >>> assert Path.from_str('["foo"]').get(data) == 'bar'

        You can escape characters by using a period.

        >>> data = {'foo.bar': 'baz'}
        >>> assert data['foo.bar'] == 'baz'
        >>> assert Path.from_str('["foo\\.bar"]').get(data) == 'baz'

        You can set and delete by using those methods instead.
        And you can mix all the above together to walk complex paths.

        >>> data = {'foo': 'bar', 'bar': 'baz'}
        >>> assert Path.from_str('[["foo"]]').get(data) == 'baz'
        >>> class Test:
        ...     foo = ['bar', 'baz']
        >>> assert Path.from_str('foo[1]').get(Test) == 'baz'

        """
        return cls(list(_parse(iter(value))))

    def get(self, obj: Any) -> Any:
        """Walk the path and get the resulting value."""
        root_obj = obj
        for node in self._nodes:
            obj = node.get(root_obj, obj)
        return obj

    def set(self, obj: Any, value: Any) -> Any:
        """Set the leaf node to the entered value."""
        root_obj = obj
        for node in self._nodes[:-1]:
            obj = node.get(root_obj, obj)
        self._nodes[-1].set(root_obj, obj, value)

    def delete(self, obj: Any) -> Any:
        """Delete the leaf node."""
        root_obj = obj
        for node in self._nodes[:-1]:
            obj = node.get(root_obj, obj)
        self._nodes[-1].delete(root_obj, obj)


STRING_DELIMITERS = {'"', "'"}
Split = Union[None, str]


def _parse(
    chars: Iterator[str],
    end: Optional[str] = None,
) -> Iterator[Union[Attr, Item, Literal]]:
    """
    Parse a string into an easy to use representation.

    -   Non-special characters are just appended to segment. It's a
        list to prevent the \$O(n^2)\$ time complexity immutable
        strings would have.

        This is later parsed by :code:`_convert` to yield its correct
        representation. This function only yields from this function.

    -   Split stores the previous form of split.

        This can be "" - no split, a . or [ for a period or bracket split,
        or None for a character that split the segment but can't split.

        An example of None would be a string literal in the middle of
        a segment 'foo"bar"baz'. This is not a legal construct.
        That should be '"foobarbaz"'.

    -   This function is recursive only when interpreting the [ split.

        This means foo[0].bar would have four segments. Both foo and 0
        will have a split of "". As they're the start of their own
        parse function. bar would have the split . as it follows a period.
        The empty list between ]. would have the split None. This is
        as "[foo]bar.baz" doesn't make much sense.
    """
    segment = []
    split: Split = ""
    for char in chars:
        if char == "\\":
            segment.append(next(chars))
        elif char in STRING_DELIMITERS:
            if segment:
                raise ValueError(
                    "String literal can't start in the middle of an attribute"
                )
            yield from _convert(split, _extract_string(chars, char))
            split = None
        elif char == ".":
            yield from _convert(split, segment)
            segment = []
            split = "."
        elif char == "[":
            if segment:
                yield from _convert(split, segment)
                segment = []
            yield from _convert("[", _parse(chars, "]"))
            split = None
        elif char == "]":
            if char == end:
                break
            raise ValueError("Found a close bracket without a matching open bracket")
        else:
            segment.append(char)
    else:
        if end:
            raise ValueError("Found an open bracket without a matching close bracket")
    if segment:
        yield from _convert(split, segment)


def _convert(
    split: Split,
    segment: Union[List[str], Iterator[Union[Attr, Item, Literal]]],
) -> Iterator[Union[Attr, Item, Literal]]:
    """
    Convert a segment into an attribute, item or literal.

    All leaf nodes are Literals, these are normally plain old strings.
    However if the first segment (split == "") starts with an integer
    then we will convert the segment to an integer. This allows us to
    index lists.

    If we have an illegal split, None, with content in the segment
    then we raise here.

    Whilst not a segment we pass the result of recursive _parse calls
    through this function. These are converted into an Item index with
    the result given to the containing Path.

    Everything else is just converted to an attribute with a path
    containing a single literal.

    You should notice that this means "1" is a valid path and would
    just return the integer 1.

    >>> assert Path.from_str('1').get(None) == 1
    """
    if split is None:
        if segment:
            raise ValueError("String literals can't end halfway through an attribute")
        return
    if split == "[":
        _segment = cast(Iterator[Union[Attr, Item, Literal]], segment)
        yield Item(Path(list(_segment)))
        return
    value = "".join(cast(List[str], segment))
    if split == "":
        if not value:
            return
        elif value[0].isnumeric():
            yield Literal(int(value))
            return
        elif value[0] in STRING_DELIMITERS:
            yield Literal(value[1:-1])
            return
    yield Attr(Path([Literal(value)]))


def _extract_string(chars: Iterator[str], literal: str) -> List[str]:
    """Extract string with matching delimiter."""
    segment = []
    for char in chars:
        if char == "\\":
            char = next(chars)
        elif char == literal:
            break
        segment.append(char)
    else:
        raise ValueError("String literal doesn't have a closing delimiter")
    return [literal] + segment + [literal]
```

To test the code just run `python foo.py` and it'll run all the tests.
When working with the code, you may want to move the `Path.from_str` tests above the class `Test`.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    class Test:
        foo = {"bar": 1, "baz": 2}
        bar = "baz"

    assert Path.from_str("foo").get(Test) == {"bar": 1, "baz": 2}
    assert Path.from_str(".foo").get(Test) == {"bar": 1, "baz": 2}
    assert Path.from_str('foo["bar"]').get(Test) == 1
    assert Path.from_str('foo["baz"]').get(Test) == 2
    assert Path.from_str("bar").get(Test) == "baz"
    assert Path.from_str("bar[0]").get(Test) == "b"
    assert Path.from_str("bar[1]").get(Test) == "a"
    assert Path.from_str("bar[2]").get(Test) == "z"

    path = Path.from_str("foo[bar]")
    assert path.get(Test) == 2
    path.set(Test, 3)
    assert path.get(Test) == 3

    data = {"foo": "bar", "bar": "baz"}
    assert Path.from_str('[["foo"]]').get(data) == "baz"

    assert Path.from_str("1") == Path([Literal(1)])
    assert Path.from_str('"a"') == Path([Literal("a")])
    assert Path.from_str("a") == Path([Attr(Path([Literal("a")]))])
    assert Path.from_str("a\\.b") == Path([Attr(Path([Literal("a.b")]))])
    assert Path.from_str("a.b") == Path(
        [Attr(Path([Literal("a")])), Attr(Path([Literal("b")]))]
    )
    assert Path.from_str(".a") == Path([Attr(Path([Literal("a")]))])
    assert Path.from_str('["a"]') == Path([Item(Path([Literal("a")]))])
    assert Path.from_str("[a]") == Path([Item(Path([Attr(Path([Literal("a")]))]))])
    assert Path.from_str("a[b]") == Path(
        [Attr(Path([Literal("a")])), Item(Path([Attr(Path([Literal("b")]))])),]
    )

    for work in ["a[b]", '"a"[b]', "[a].b", "[a][b]"]:
        try:
            Path.from_str(work)
        except:
            print(work)
            raise

    for fail in ["[a]b", 'a"b"', '"b"c', '[a]"b"', '"a', 'a"', "[a", "a]"]:
        try:
            ret = Path.from_str(fail)
        except:
            pass
        else:
            print(fail, ret)
            assert False

    import doctest

    doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a quick answer. I don't know exactly what other constraints you have, but it feels very clumsy to have to do something like this:

```
path = Path.from_str("foo[bar]")
assert path.get(Test) == 2
path.set(Test, 3)
assert path.get(Test) == 3
```

I would instead consider for `Path` to take the object the path will be taken off and be a wrapper for `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` (and probably `__delitem__` as well, for completeness sake), so that this snippet could become:

```
test = PathWrapper(Test)
assert test["foo[bar]"] == 2
test["foo[bar]"] = 3
assert test["foo[bar]"] == 3
```

This has the advantage that it would also work as a class decorator, so you can add this functionality to classes already upon definition if wanted. Implementation left as an exercise ;)

The tests for the internal representation of some common paths would then probably use some `PathWrapper._internal_model` property or something.

In addition, as soon as your tests become more than three cases or so, I would recommend going for a more programmatic way. For most of your cases an array of input and expected output would be fine to iterate over, but not for the cases where you modify the path. It might be worth it to at least use the `unittest` module, which does not add too much overhead (code wise). For the `doctest` module you probably have too many test cases already.

Comment: I was thinking of adding a top level function for get, set and del. Do you think that's better or worse than you've proposed? I'm confused what `Path._internal_model` is, is that meant to be `PathWrapper._internal_model`? I agree with the last paragraph, but given that [pytest has doctest support](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/doctest.html) I'd just use that, my setup's just a bit messed up atm

Answer (score 4):

First of all, nice code. I like the documentation and the type hints. One thing you could do is to follow a style convention for your docstrings; see some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898572/what-is-the-standard-python-docstring-format).

For me, I think the most glaring thing is that you have all of your tests in a main function. I would separate these tests by type and move them over to individual files, and I would personally use (and recommend) pytest; you could pass in an instance of your class as a fixture. If you end up with a few files of tests, I'd keep these in a separate folder and would create a `Makefile` for running them.

One thing I noticed is that you specify return type `Any` for some methods that don't really return anything, such as `Attr.set`.

You also have some repeated code that you could refactor out; see the methods of `Path`:

```
def set(self, obj: Any, value: Any) -> Any:
    """Set the leaf node to the entered value."""
    root_obj = obj
    for node in self._nodes[:-1]:
        obj = node.get(root_obj, obj)
    self._nodes[-1].set(root_obj, obj, value)

def delete(self, obj: Any) -> Any:
    """Delete the leaf node."""
    root_obj = obj
    for node in self._nodes[:-1]:
        obj = node.get(root_obj, obj)
    self._nodes[-1].delete(root_obj, obj)
```

which could be something like:

```
def set(self, root_obj: Any, value: Any) -> None:
    """Set the leaf node to the entered value."""
    self._nodes[-1].set(
        root_obj,
        find_node(root_obj),
        value
    )

def delete(self, root_obj: Any, value: Any) -> None:
    """Delete the leaf node."""
    self._nodes[-1].delete(
        root_obj,
        find_node(root_obj)
    )

def find_node(self, root_obj: Any) -> Any:
    """Traverses tree and finds leaf node"""
    obj = root_obj
    for node in self._nodes[:-1]:
        obj = node.get(root_obj, obj)
    return obj
```

Finally, there are some places where I think you would benefit from more whitespace---one example is just before the following in the function `_parse`.

```
    if segment:
        yield from _convert(split, segment)
```

Comment: Please can you elaborate on your first point. Am I not following conventions? Pretty sure I am, so any additional information here - pointing to where I'm not - would be helpful. I'm not a fan of make, I use tox and nox. As for whitespace black's output can be good, but some of it is aweful.

Comment: I mean to use the docstring to clarify arguments and return type, and to mention possible exceptions and errors raised.
About make vs tox/nox, your preference; I just like having a separate way of running the tests.
I agree about black. I just got a bit caught reading some of the lines because I first thought they were logically closer to the functionality above, but whitespace is a preference so that was a very minor comment.

Comment: Could I clarify do you mean "to clarify {argument and return} type", "to clarify argument and {return} type" or "to clarify {argument and return} value(s)". Because clarifying the type seems a bit redundant. Yeah using make/tox/nox as a command to run tests is nice :)

Comment: The third in this case since we're dealing with `Any`—perhaps I should be more careful with my terminology...
Can I ask: how do you like dealing with tox/nox? Are you working in Python exclusively?

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. :) Yes I work exclusively with Python. I used tox for a little bit, but hit a wall where I needed to have more control than an ini. So I mostly use nox now. Here is the skeleton [nox.py](https://github.com/Peilonrayz/skeleton_py/blob/master/noxfile.py) file I use. To note the `[:-1]` is not superfluous and actually breaks the code so very severely. It changes the path from `foo.bar` to `foo.bar.bar`.